# What is the correct Windows setlocale for the United Arab Emirates?

Tags: windows, internationalization, locale

Dear Arab reader from the United Arab Emirates,

I am on my way to port my Linux code to pure Windows. This code, among others, is pretending to turn a Gregorian date (internally a Unix date) to an Hijri date and display the result using the Arab United Emirates locale.

The true reason why I need you is to correctly set your nation's locale under Windows and its C runtime. So far I have tested many combinations of the "Arabic_United Arab Emirates.1256" string as clearly documented as such by Microsoft. All my attempts returned null. The problem I face seems to be very specific to the United Arab Emirates as I can set with no problem : Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256 or Arabic_Egypt.1256.

So if there is some developer over there owning the Microsoft Visual Studio suite installed on his Windows PC, would he be kind to build and run the following pure Windows C code with the following commands under a CMD terminal ?

```
/*
 * File : foo.c
 *
 * To build :
 *   C:\path>vcvars64
 *   C:\path>cl /c /Tp foo.c
 *   C:\path>link /subsystem:console foo.obj kernel32.lib
 *
 * Goal:
 *   find the Windows C locale suited for the United Arab Emirates
 *
 * OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Entreprise N
 */
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <locale.h>

 void usage(char *str)
 {
    printf("Usage: %s <CRT localename>");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   wchar_t localename[100];

   if (argc != 2) usage(argv[0]);
   MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, localename, sizeof(localename));
   wprintf(L"%s\n",_wsetlocale(LC_TIME,localename));
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
}
```

Provided your Regional and Language Windows settings (Control Panel) are set to Arabic (United Arab Emirates), then you should run the code with:

```
C:\path>foo ""
```

and reply to this post with what you read.

On my Windows 7 and with my Windows regional settings, the code above and the provided CMD commands tonight display me: "French_France.1252"

I do fear to turn myself my Notebook to Arabic (United Arab Emirates). I am a pure French citizen trying to best satisfy the worldwide IT community through his public Web site. I am absolutely not introduced to any Arabic language, even more an Arabic regional dialect. I do really fear that I shall have to definitely say goodbye to Windows if I turn my regional settings to your country settings. My Windows Notebook has been shipped with Windows pre-installed. So no CD to reinstall Windows.

To any replier to this post, many thanks in advance to you. Much more if you bring the expected answer, if possible the solution.

Philippe Vouters

Comment: I think it's a bit much to ask someone else to do something on their computer that you consider too risky to do on your own.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Arabic_U.A.E..1256

**Long answer:**

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumLocalesProcEx(LPWSTR lpLocaleId, DWORD dwFlags, LPARAM lParam) {
    WCHAR name[10];
    if (GetLocaleInfoEx(lpLocaleId, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, name, _countof(name))) {
        WCHAR *crtLocale = _wsetlocale(LC_TIME, name);
        wprintf(L"%s   %s    %s\n", lpLocaleId, name, crtLocale);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
...
EnumSystemLocalesEx(EnumLocalesProcEx, LOCALE_ALL, 0, NULL);
```

This will give you a complete list of all the locales supported.
(or course, it would be nice to save/restore the original locale, because it will be messed up by that _wsetlocale.

**Extras:**

1. You can use wmain instead of main:

   ```
   int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
   ```

   That way you can call _wsetlocale(LC_TIME, argv[1]), no need for MultiByteToWideChar.
2. You should pass a parameter to the printf in usage:

   ```
   printf("Usage: %s <CRT localename>", str);
   ```

   not

   ```
   printf("Usage: %s <CRT localename>");
   ```
3. You can also go with wprintf in usage, and be Unicode all the way.
4. You might want to take a look at "Using Generic-Text Mappings"
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dzey6h6.aspx

   Using things like _tprintf instead of printf/wprintf might give you a chance to reuse code between Windows/Linux (although the POSIX international support is quite poor)
5. You might want to take a loot at this article + tool: http://mihai-nita.net/2007/12/19/tounicode-automating-some-of-the-steps-of-unicode-code-conversion-windows/

   It might help you migrate your code to use the Generic-Text functions.
   (that way you can define UNICODE and _UNICODE and get a fully Unicode application)
6. Don't expect wonders from the Windows console. It is notoriously poor at rendering foreign strings. You will have to set the system locale get decent results.