# How could read and write Arabic number in my app that i have develop (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠)?

Tags: python, encoding, pyqt

Just I want read and write Arabic number (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠) in my app that has designed with Qt designer and Python , as i know that encoding(utf-8), that will read any symbol in the world and I believe that but why it is keep going transfer arabic number to English number although my source file CSV file encoding-utf8?

simply , how could I write arabic number like what we can do in Mycrosoft word as example , we can write (1234567890) and we can write (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠) when just we change the language from English to Arabic , how can I achieve that in my app too?

- I have noticed that i couldn't write Arabic numbers either in Pycharm or in Qt designer !!! or in Google website too (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠).
- I have noticed when i copy and paste the Arabic number (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠) from any place except the CSV file itself , the app can read Arabic number , but when i try to write Arabic number inside the csv file it will written by Arabic but i have to write Arabic letter with it,  i mean i couldn't write as example (٤٥٦٧) without i write some arabic letter the csv file itself convert the arabic number to English when i writing arabic number.

this is my CSV file

[image]

my app change arabic number to English number

[image]

how can i write arabic number inside Qt designer too (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠)?

[image]

```
import sys
from os import path
import pandas as pd
def put_items_in_cells(self):
    #all csv_files in csv_files directory !!!
    reader1 = path.join(path.dirname(__file__),"csv_files","جدول 
    بيانات 
    الوسائط البحرية.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv(reader1,delimiter=";",encoding="UTF-8")

    for pos,d in df.iterrows():
        num1,category,num2,num3,num4,place,num5 =\
        d["رقم الواسطة"],d["فئة الواسطة"],\
        d["رقم الهيكس Epirb"],d["رقم الهيكس PLB"],\
        d["رقم MMSI"],d["منطقة عمل الواسطة"],d["رمز النداء"]

        print(num1)

        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()

        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

        #print(rowPosition)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, 
        QTableWidgetItem(str(num1)))
```

The code above works fine except keeping transfer arabic number to English although written by Arabic number inside CSV file.

When I have tried to check the encoding what if works properly or not by writhing this code /

```
    print(ord(u'١'))
```

and the result inside pycharm is/
        1633

```
    print(chr(1633))
```

result/
         ١

```
    print(ord(u'٢'))
```

result/
        1634

```
    print(chr((1634)))
```

result/
        ٢

I have noticed each number in arabic language have a code point. I don't know what i am missing here?

there is no any error messages the code works fine except keep changing the Arabic numbers (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠)to English numbers (1234567890) without asking that.

I want just write arabic number as will as writing English number inside my app , like microsoft word ,if i can i do that, please help me to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your locale correctly for this to work. Number parsing and formatting depends on locale settings. E.g. your environment can be set to an American English locale and you get a different result from French in France, or from Simplified Chinese in Hong Kong.

So first of all you need to figure out how to do that, which is going to depend on your OS and what your toolkit supports. For Qt based apps refer to: [the Qt locale documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Locales).

On a POSIX system you can typically configure the locale in a fine grained fashion through environment [`LC_*` variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html). Other environment variables worth trying are `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`, e.g. `LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"` or `LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"` for British English with UTF-8 character encoding by default.

Comment: my OS is  windows 8.1 single language 64 bit ,python 3.7.3 within Anaconda, and Qt designer (not  Q creator ) do i need C++ code for do the job ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) aware parser:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL)

n = locale.atoi("١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠")
print(n)
```

This also provides `format_string` which can adapt to local ways to output numbers.

A number itself doesn't hold the information about what script it is presented in, which is why it is lost when you read then write a CSV. I suspect the `csv` module lacks a clear way to request Arabic numeral output.

The short path to displaying your numbers is probably to use something like `QTableWidgetItem(locale.format_string("%f",num1)))` (replacing `str`). I'm not sure how your locale has to be set; it might be `'ar-AE'` or [`'Arabic_U.A.E..1256'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520712/what-is-the-correct-windows-setlocale-for-the-united-arab-emirates), for instance.